# Can't insert arabic characters into oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, character-encoding, arabic

I got problems while reading arabic characters from oracle in java using JDBC driver, the main problem was i couldn't find the proper character encoding to get the correct data , but i solved the problem manually using this method:

```
public static String cleanORCLString(String s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("UTF16");
    String x = new String(bytes, "Cp1256");

    String finalS = x.substring(3);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(finalS);

    for(int k = sb.length() - 1 ; k > 0 ; k--) {

        if(!isEven(k)) {

            sb.deleteCharAt(k);

        }

    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

this method give me the correct characters like its shown in database, but when I try to update/insert arabic data, it save wrong characters.
For example:  my text saved in database as "?????????" instead of "مرحبا".

This is the way I connect to oracle database.

```
URL = ORCLConnProperties.ORCL_THIN_PREFIX + orclProp.getIpAddress()
            + orclProp.getPortNumber() + ORCLConnProperties.ORCL_THIN_SUFIX;

// URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.0.12:1521:ORCL


    System.out.println("URL: " + URL);

    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    connectionProps.put("characterEncoding", "Cp1256");
    connectionProps.put("useUnicode", "true");
    connectionProps.put("user", orclProp.getUserName());
    connectionProps.put("password", orclProp.getPassword());

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
        System.exit(1);
    }


    myDriver = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();

    DriverManager.registerDriver(myDriver);

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, connectionProps);
```

please help me in solving this issue ?
Thanks.

New Note:

Database itself don't use UTF16 character set, but

> "the JDBC OCI driver transfers the data from the server to the client
>   in the character set of the database. Depending on the value of the
>   NLS_LANG environment variable, the driver handles character set
>   conversions: OCI converts the data from the database character set to
>   UTF-8. The JDBC OCI driver then passes the UTF-8 data to the JDBC
>   Class Library, where the UTF-8 data is converted to UTF-16."

this note is mentioned here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/advanc.htm

Comment: Do you have the orai18n.jar on your class path? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/global.htm#JJDBC28643

Comment: no i don't have it, am going to try that :) and thanks for the information and reference link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you may check the NLS_CHARACTERSET parameter of your database using 
the SQL*PLUS command :-

select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

the result should be

PARAMETER

VALUE

NLS_CHARACTERSET

AR8MSWIN1256

if it's not, you have to change the value of this parameter using :-

- hit WINDOWS KEY + r on your keyboard
- write :- SQLPLUS sys as sysdba
- press Enter then enter the password or just hit another Enter
- issue the following commands :
- SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
- STARTUP RESTRICT
- ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE AR8MSWIN1256;
- ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET AR8MSWIN1256;
- SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
- STARTUP
- change the value of the NLS_LANG registry string into  AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256

  ***if your operating system is a flavor of UNIX*** use

**AR8ISO8859P6** instead of **AR8MSWIN1256** as the value of **NLS_CHARACTERSET**

- DON'T use National datatypes (i.e NVARCHAR, NTEXT, or NCLOB ) in your database unless you are going to use other languages than (Arabic and English) inside your database
- AR8MSWIN1256 character set is sufficient for mixing arabic and english inside the same field (as far as I know).

**TAKEN FROM**

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMphHE78imM
- https://ksadba.wordpress.com/2008/06/10/how-to-show-arabic-characters-in-your-client-app/

Comment: Thanks alot it an old question that i asked, but this was the solution

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET ...` is de-supported since Oracle 10g. You should not use it, you may destroy your database. Follow the official guideline from Oracle: [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011) or use the [DMU - Database Migration Assistant for Unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E89575_01/DUMAG/toc.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Check your oracle version. if it old it can't support UTF16.

here is an article -- hope it will be useful.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch6unicode.htm

Comment: Oracle version is 11 G Enterprise Edition 11.1.0.7.0 , i have already created tables from another program with this data, and as i mentioned  that i can read the data by converting it from UTF16 to Cp1256, but my issue in inserting and updating to the database.

Comment: I added a new note to make things more clear about my issue, please check it if you can @user3082691