# Inserting arabic characters in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to insert Arabic characters in Oracle 11g, however the data is being inserted as  question marks. I searched around and it seems i have to change the character encoding... But i am not sure how, and whether will it affect my database. Any help please ?

```
UPDATE LAM_INVESTMENT
SET INVESTMENT='ل'
WHERE KEY=11;
```

I tried updating from within SQL developer, also same outcome.

Comment: Please Try my Answer here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610462/cant-insert-arabic-characters-into-oracle-database/42521619#42521619

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if your database is capable to store Arabic characters by

```
SELECT * 
from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
WHERE PARAMETER IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');
```

If you get values like `AL32UTF8`, `AL16UTF16` or `WE8ISO8859P6` you are fine and DB is able to store such characters.

In SQL Developer go to Tools / Preferences / Environment / Encoding and select `UTF-8`.

Set an Environment Variable to `NLS_LANG=ARABIC_AMERICA.AL32UTF8` or similar, you can also do `NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8` in order to keep default/existing language and territory. Alternatively you can set is also in your Registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` (for 32 bit), resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\NLS_LANG` (for 64 bit).

Then it should work.

Changing your local character set (i.e. NLS_LANG) does never affect any existing data in database.

Comment: I followed what you suggest and restart my pc but nothing changed NOTE i am migrating data from access 2003 to oracle 12c so I am opening the access data from sql  developers  is there anything else to do ?
characters in access display right but when I open it from sql developer I get question marks instead of arabic characters

Comment: SQL Developer is Java based which does not use `NLS_LANG` setting, Have a look at SQL Developer program settings (I don't know the menu by head as I don't use this tool so much)

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating using the function UNISTR and the unicode 0644, to circumvent Oracle client configurations (in case they do not support Unicode):

```
UPDATE LAM_INVESTMENT
SET INVESTMENT=UNISTR('\0644')
WHERE KEY=11;
```

It may or may not work, depending on the data type of column investment and on your character set (or national character set).

[Unicode table reference](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0644/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you column type is nvarchar, have you tried to use the next query:

```
UPDATE LAM_INVESTMENT
SET INVESTMENT=N'ل'
WHERE KEY=11;
```

I had the same situation with korean language. Hope this approach helps you as well as it helped me.