# migrating database from access 2003 to oracle Arabic characters are shown as question marks

Tags: oracle, ms-access, oracle11g, database-migration

**UPDATE**

> as answer below shows that is error couse by JDBC so is there any
>   other suggestion to migrate access database to oracle database other
>   than using toad and the hard way to do it because trigger views
>   sequences wont be imported by that way so I have to create them by my
>   self??! :S

I am migrating database from `access 2003` to `oracle database 12c` but Arabic characters are shown as question marks at the step where you connect to access database using `SQL developers`

I followed what you [suggest at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188292/inserting-arabic-characters-in-oracle-11g) and restart my pc but nothing changed

**NOTE**

when opening `.mdb file` from access Arabic characters shown right but when opening it from `SQL developers` I get question marks instead of arabic characters
is there anything else to do ?

I run that query as @krokodilko suggested and I get below result

```
select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter like '%CHAR%'


NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AR8MSWIN1256


select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter like '%LANG%';

NLS_LANGUAGE    ENGLISH
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   ENGLISH
```

by the way when I open another Oracle schema Arabic characters show correctly dose access has special encoding ?

Comment: Please run in SQL-Developer: `select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter like '%CHAR%'` and append it's result to the question. Please also run second query `select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter like '%LANG%';` and append its result to the question too.

Comment: @krokodilko I did run both queries and edit my post thank you in advance

Comment: @krokodilko I have run it under sys user when I run it under connection linked to access database I get that message `[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'nls_session_parameters'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.` i think that okay just to let you know

Comment: What version of SQL Developer and Java runtime do you have? (Starting with JDK 8, the JDBC-ODBC Bridge is no longer included.)

Comment: @LiborStefek the one comes installed when I installed oracle database 12c from help >> about sql developer  Version 3.2.20.10 Java(TM) Platform 1.6.0_75 ...   I am following that gudie to migrate from access to oracle 

[link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/convert-step-access-1947169.html) another suggestion ?

Comment: by the way when I open another Oracle schema Arabic characters show correctly dose access has special encoding ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this looks like a problem with JDBC-ODBC Bridge. It does not work properly with the Access ODBC driver when text includes Unicode characters.

See other questions regarding MS Access over JDBC-ODBC Bridge like this:
[Reading Unicode characters from an Access database via JDBC-ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192750/reading-unicode-characters-from-an-access-database-via-jdbc-odbc/20982205#20982205).
There is also proposed solution which may work for general Java-to-MSAccess connection using pure Java JDBC driver ([UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html)):
[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc)

But, your question is about using SQL Developer for migration, so, it is not a solution for you, since SQL Developer supports only limited number of JDBC drivers. Not UCanAccess.

Hard-way is better than no-way.

Comment: ummm thanks for your help .. would you suggest away to migrate access database to oracle ? becasue it seems I am going to do it with hard way like the [video link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtPhvXEK3qc) :S that not seems professional sadly I was hoping to learn the professional way

Comment: I think, using Toad is not much different to doing the same task in SQL Developer. If that is one time task.

Comment: yea that one time task

Comment: trigger views sequences wont be imported by that way so I have to create them by my self :S