# Unable to insert arabic character into oracle Database in proper arabic format

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, arabic, datastore

I am inserting below data into table:

`String arabicText = "مصرف التجاري السوري"`, it is stored as `Ø§Ù„Ù…ØµØ±Ù¿ Ø§Ù„ØªØ¬Ø§Ø±ÙŠ Ø§Ù„Ø³` in *Oracle DB* which is wrong.

If data is inserted as `¿¿¿¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿` then it will show  correct in DBever S/w.Data should not be encoded into `Ø§Ù„Ù…ØµØ±Ù¿ Ø§Ù„ØªØ¬Ø§Ø±ÙŠ Ø§Ù„Ø³` this format.

Tried below code for the same:

Try 1:

```
String arabicText = new String(arabicText.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Try 2:

```
String arabicText = new String(messag.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Try 3:

```
 String arabicText = new String(messag.getBytes("utf-8"), "utf-8");
```

also checked

```
SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

which is AL32UTF8

Comment: Can you edit your question and  include the `INSERT` query and the table definition ?

Comment: Also specify how do you check the inserted string: the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is correct so, perhaps, you corrupt the string when you read/display it, not when you insert it.

Comment: String arabicText = "مصرف التجاري السوري";
byte[] bytes = arabicText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Comment: What Java version are you using? What Oracle database version are you using? What platform is Java running on? What platform is Oracle running on? What JDBC driver are you using? Is the Java code running inside the database, as in a Java stored procedure? Or do you have a Java program that interacts with the database via JDBC?

Comment: Stopping using `String.getBytes()` and and `String(byte[], Charset)` unless you are actually dealing with conversion from byte arrays to strings and vice versa. Unlike some other programming languages, you cannot choose the encoding for strings. Java does it for you. It's an implementation detail. All strings support the full Unicode character set. And there is no ambiguity whether the strings should be interpreted as character set X or Y. If a string conversion is needed, the Oracle driver will do it.

Comment: If it works on one system but not on others, they likely use different *default* encodings. Make sure you set an explicit encoding for Tomcat. Otherwise it might use the default one and interpret HTTP requests incorrectly. `String.getBytes()`, `String(byte[])` and similar methods without explicit character set are also problematic. They will take the *default* one, which differs from system to system. Search for them. In many cases, the best fix will be to remove them. Oracle is unlikely to be the issue. Tomcat, log files and console output are more likely the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check your **file encoding settings** in your IDE and make sure utf8 for avoiding like this characters *"Ø§Ù„Ù…ØµØ±Ù¿ Ø§Ù„Ø"* , here are hints for Intellij IDEA  :

[Intellij IDEA - Jetbrains File Encodings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-file-encodings.html)

for the eclipse , this link might be help for you :

[eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180981/how-to-support-utf-8-encoding-in-eclipse)

secondly , please check NLS_CHARACTERSET parameter of your database or database settings. Here are the solutions that might be related your question

[check NLS_CHARACTERSET -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610462/cant-insert-arabic-characters-into-oracle-database?rq=2)

[check NLS_CHARACTERSET -2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188292/inserting-arabic-characters-in-oracle-11g#:%7E:text=In%20SQL%20Developer%20go%20to,default%2Fexisting%20language%20and%20territory.)

Comment: Actually with embedded tomcat data is inserted into DB in proper arabic format.But when deployed at client side and also in local system with external tomcat it's stored in encoded which is incorrect.